# Power button stopped working it fall down

Tags: hardware, asus-zenfone-2

I am using Asus ZenFone since 8 months but after fall down the power button stopped working which is actually creating a problem for me. What can I do about it?

Comment: If you don't have warranity than you can try installing custom rom that have feature to enable volume rocker to wake up (volume buttons). And use some app to lock phone or double tap on status bar to lock.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you still have warranty then try to repair it for free.

**2)** You can also try to repair the ZenFone for money. But i think it will be too expensiv.

**3)** If you doint want to spend money the install an Power-Off-App like 
[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luutinhit.sensorsforconver) one.
And for Wakeup you can try to install/enable [Double-Tap to Wake](https://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-6089-1-1.html).

I hope i could help you:)

P.S If there's an other way then let me know.